# Javascript children' constructor name

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

### Question

How one could retrieve the children' (of any inheritance depth level) constructor name?

### Explanation

Let us have class `Cat` that extends the `Model` class. And the class `Kitten` that extends the `Cat` class.

What I want is printed to the console (for example) string `"Kitten"` when one creates the `Kitten` class instance and the string `"Cat"` when one creates the `Cat` class instance.

The trick is that the code that outputs the constructor name should be located at the base (`Model` for the example shown) class.

*Note:* I'm good at Ruby, compared (in the scope of myself) to Javascript. So the *"pseudo-code"* shall be the Ruby-ish one =)

```
# pseudo-Ruby-code
class Model
  def initialize
    console.log(self.constructor.toString())
  end
end

class Cat << Model
  # something goes here
end

class Kitten << Cat
  # and here too
end

# shows "Model"
Model.new

# shows "Kitten"
Kitten.new

# shows "Cat"
Cat.new
```

Comment: When you try to do class inheritance like this in JavaScript, God performs `delete new Kitten()` -- couldn't help myself.

Comment: How about passing an argument to the `super` constructor?

Comment: @Jack let's assume classes do have some bodies

Comment: @Amberlamps could you provide any examples?

Comment: This could, probably, be done with the constructor pattern, and `typeof`, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @RyanKinal what's the `constructor` pattern?

Comment: [constructor pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#constructorpatternjavascript)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it using Coffee-Script.

```
class Model

    constructor: (animal = "Model") ->

        console.log animal;



class Cat extends Model

    constructor: (animal = "Cat") ->

        super animal


class Kitten extends Cat

    constructor: (animal = "Kitten") ->

        super animal

new Kitten()

// => Kitten
```

This is the compiled JavaScript:

```
var Cat, Kitten, Model,
  __hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty,
  __extends = function(child, parent) { for (var key in parent) { if (__hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key]; } function ctor() { this.constructor = child; } ctor.prototype = parent.prototype; child.prototype = new ctor(); child.__super__ = parent.prototype; return child; };

Model = (function() {

  function Model(animal) {
    if (animal == null) {
      animal = "Model";
    }
    console.log(animal);
  }

  return Model;

})();

Cat = (function(_super) {

  __extends(Cat, _super);

  function Cat(animal) {
    if (animal == null) {
      animal = "Cat";
    }
    Cat.__super__.constructor.call(this, animal);
  }

  return Cat;

})(Model);

Kitten = (function(_super) {

  __extends(Kitten, _super);

  function Kitten(animal) {
    if (animal == null) {
      animal = "Kitten";
    }
    Kitten.__super__.constructor.call(this, animal);
  }

  return Kitten;

})(Cat);

new Kitten();
```

You can try it yourself [here](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aclass%20Model%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%3a%20%28animal%20=%20%22Model%22%29%20-%3E%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log%20animal;%0A%0A%0A%0Aclass%20Cat%20extends%20Model%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%3a%20%28animal%20=%20%22Cat%22%29%20-%3E%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super%20animal%0A%0A%0Aclass%20Kitten%20extends%20Cat%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%3a%20%28animal%20=%20%22Kitten%22%29%20-%3E%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super%20animal)

Comment: Do you know the way to perform this without modifying the children classes' constructors? Only the parent one =) E.g. without passing any additional arguments to the parent' constructor.

Comment: @shybovycha: If you create an instance of a class that inherits from a different class, the parent constructor is not triggered automatically. I am not super experienced in OOP, but in what language is creating a child instance automatically executing its parent constructor?